# BufferedOutputStream не записаваются в файл

Tags: java

```
public class WriteXMLFile {

    public static void main(String argv[]) {

      try {

        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        // root elements
        Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
        Element rootElement = doc.createElement("heroes_data");
        doc.appendChild(rootElement);

        // staff elements
        Element staff = doc.createElement("hero");
        rootElement.appendChild(staff);

        // set attribute to staff element
        //Attr attr = doc.createAttribute("id");
        //attr.setValue("1");
        //staff.setAttributeNode(attr);

        // shorten way
        // staff.setAttribute("id", "1");

        // firstname elements
        Element firstname = doc.createElement("firstname");
        firstname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("artem"));
        staff.appendChild(firstname);

        // age elements
        Element salary = doc.createElement("age");
        salary.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("18"));
        staff.appendChild(salary);

        // write the content into xml file
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);

        //StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("C:\\file.xml"));

        // Output to console for testing

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
        transformer.transform(source, result);
        String strResult = writer.toString();

        FileOutputStream out=new FileOutputStream("base"); 
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(out);
        // перевод строки в байты
        byte[] buffer = strResult.getBytes();
        bos.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        out.close();

        System.out.println(strResult);

      } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        pce.printStackTrace();
      } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
        tfe.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        //System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Возможно потому, что вы его не закрываете.

Answer (score 0):

У `BufferedOutputStream`  необходимо вызвать метод `flush()`, для того чтобы произошла запись на диск

Если Вы добавите строчку `bos.flush();` между `byte[] buffer = strResult.getBytes();` и `out.close();`

то данные в файле появятся...

Код целиком:

```js
public class WriteXMLFile {

    public static void main(String argv[]) {

      try {

        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        // root elements
        Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
        Element rootElement = doc.createElement("heroes_data");
        doc.appendChild(rootElement);

        // staff elements
        Element staff = doc.createElement("hero");
        rootElement.appendChild(staff);

        // set attribute to staff element
        //Attr attr = doc.createAttribute("id");
        //attr.setValue("1");
        //staff.setAttributeNode(attr);

        // shorten way
        // staff.setAttribute("id", "1");

        // firstname elements
        Element firstname = doc.createElement("firstname");
        firstname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("artem"));
        staff.appendChild(firstname);

        // age elements
        Element salary = doc.createElement("age");
        salary.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("18"));
        staff.appendChild(salary);

        // write the content into xml file
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);

        //StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("C:\\file.xml"));

        // Output to console for testing

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
        transformer.transform(source, result);
        String strResult = writer.toString();

        FileOutputStream out=new FileOutputStream("base"); 
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(out);
        // перевод строки в байты
        byte[] buffer = strResult.getBytes();
        bos.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        bos.flush();
        out.close();

        System.out.println(strResult);

      } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        pce.printStackTrace();
      } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
        tfe.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        //System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
      }
    }
}
```